# Command remote PLC with modbus protocol using Python

Tags: python, remote-access, modbus, plc, modem

I'm new in the modbus world, and I'm looking for what tools I can use for this scenario:

[image: General Architecture]

Central server is a Web app, written in Python. This Web App is exposed on a public IP. I have several remote PLCs, each of them has a Modem 3G connected and understands Modbus protocol. From the Web App, I must be able to show some synoptics with the data from the PLCs, and send to remote PLCs some commands.
Central server has a DB with data from remote PLCs. Normally I would associate to every PLC an industrial computer running a Python client that transfers data from the PLC to the central server through HTTP calls, but in this particular case I cannot have any hardware capable of executing logic with the PLC nor can I configure the PLC to send data to a remote host.

So, my idea is to have:

- a VPN on each modem, so I have a secure communication channel to use and I know all the IP of my clients;
- a Modbus client, which gets get the data from remote PLCs at regular intervals;
- the Modbus client converts the data from the PLCs to a format the  central server understands;
- the Modbus client writes the converted data to the DB of the central server;
- Modbus client and central Web App will be on the same machine;

So my question is: are there already existing Python libraries that can help me to implement at least the fist part of modbus client? Specifically, I need a library that is able to use Modbus protocol in order to read and write the data on the remote PLCs.

Comment: Please clarify your requirements; it's not really clear whether you will be setting up a Modbus client (to poll the PLC's) or a Modbus server (that the PLC's send data to) or a combination of both. Modbus uses a client/server model; the server just waits for an incoming request and responds. There are a number of Modbus python libraries; probably best to start with [pymodbus](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html).

Comment: @Brits thank you for your correction, I changed my initial post. Still the pymodbus it's the best choice for you?

Comment: I think that pymodbus is likely to provide the functionality you need and one of the reasons I suggest it is because its well documented (so you should be able to assess if it meets your needs fairly quickly).